# Sublime starts without menu bar

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext2

Under Ubuntu in a VirtualBox
I have installed Sublime in /opt and created a link (ln) in /usr/bin called sublime

When I just call sublime from a terminal window or using the Ubunto key in the task bar Sublime starts without the menu bar in the top of the window. (So it is impossible to a menu to save e.g.)

When I start sublime with sudo sublime then everything is ok, but then I need to give the password with every start of the program.

How can I just start the program without sudo?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Sublime in a different directory.
Your home directory should be ok, but so is any other directory where you are allowed to save files without using sudo.

Edit: I see now that I misunderstood your question, so it's not surprising that it isn't working this way. Sorry!

Comment: I suppose you mean the 'real' files, not the link?

Comment: Just tried your suggestion but it doesn't make any difference

Comment: Mhh strange.
I'll try to reproduce this issue later.
However, yes, I meant the real files.

Comment: Great, thanks! the bug is really annoying and I am at my wits end.

Answer (score 0):

To reset Sublime menu please do in Terminal:

initctl restart unity-panel-service

Hope this will help you :)