# Sublime Text editor opens with no menu bar unless started with sudo

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 on VirtualBox 4.3.6, running on Windows 7. I have installed the VirtualBox Guest Additions on Ubuntu.

I have used [this .deb file](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/sublime-text-2) to install Sublime Text, which seems to work fine except that it has no menu bar unless started with `sudo` privileges.

Using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to try to enable the menu shows only a **Hide Menu** option, so it clearly thinks it is currently being displayed.

I am seeing this behaviour for both Sublime Text 2 and Sublime Text 3.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem may be?

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252271) that relates to similar symptoms, but the problem wasn't resolved.

Comment: This works for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/37353024/1358777

Answer (score 8):

If you are starting from a desktop shortcut you can edit the .desktop file's Exec line to be something like
`Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 /usr/bin/sublime-text`

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452390/eclipse-menus-dont-show-up-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10) for an example of how a similar problem was solved for eclipse.

Comment: this works, but if you have an entry in ~/.local/share/applications, you need to edit that one

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simple solution that worked for me

Close the Sublime Text 3, if it is open. Open and edit the file `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/Session.sublime_session` to make sure that, "menu_visible" is "true" in all places in that file.

```
"menu_visible": true,
```

Source: http://www.thefourtheye.in/2014/01/un-hiding-menu-bar-in-sublime-text-3.html

Comment: lol. I had the same problem in my new installation of Ubuntu and I didn't remember I blogged about it :D

Answer (score 5):

I solved in Ubuntu16.04!
Sublime installation path is **/opt/**

*sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop*

Add `env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0`  in `Exec=` before `/opt/`*
as shown in fig.

[image: Sublime Config Example]

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu create this file `sublime` in /usr/bin/

```
#!/bin/bash
env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 /opt/sublime/sublime_text $@ 2>/dev/null &
```

Then `chmod +x sublime`. Put it in your executable path and you're good to go!  If you have sublime in a different location you'll have to set that at  this part '/opt/sublime/sublime_text'

You'll want to have errors routed to null since Glib throws up warnings (it's a known Ubuntu issue).

Answer (score 1):

Wipe out any saved Sublime editor settings, probably in ~/.sublime or similar.

Answer (score -1):

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> then type vmenu
Select `Toggle menu` and enter.
then check it.