# Showing menu bar in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I got the Sublime Text editor from here.... http://sublimetext.com/3

I've googled this a lot and even after doing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> I don't see an option to 'Show Menu'.

Here is a section of my `.config/sublime-text-3/Local/Session.sublime_session`:

```json
"menu_visible": true,
"output.find_results":
{
    "height": 0.0
},
```

and

```json
"distraction_free":
{
    "menu_visible": true,
    "show_minimap": false,
    "show_open_files": false,
    "show_tabs": false,
    "side_bar_visible": false,
    "status_bar_visible": false
},
```

But I can see the menu bar neither in default state nor in Distraction Free mode

I'm at a loss as to how to see the menu bar. I have an unregistered version by the way.

Comment: Which revision of ST3 and OS are you using ?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I got the Sublime Text editor from here.... http://www.sublimetext.com/3

Answer (score 88):

- Invoke the command palette with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
- Type `menu`
- Select `View: Toggle Menu`

Comment: I do Ctrl+Shift+P and when I type menu nothing appears.

Comment: Some research shows it is some kind of bug with ubuntu, try looking at [some related topics](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&p=29721). [Try this too](http://www.thefourtheye.in/2014/01/un-hiding-menu-bar-in-sublime-text-3.html).

Comment: It's strange. I tried F10, and the menu comes up but it is at the top of the screen and not where Sublime Text is. Setting menu_visible:true did not work in Session.sublime_session. It HAS to be a bug.

Comment: This works fine with Sublime Text 3 on elementary OS. :)

Answer (score 10):

If the above solution doesn't work for someone, try:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

This should work !
I was having this problem with other apps too... So I just reset the whole thing.

Comment: Didn't need to use the reset command.
Just relaunching Unity did it for me.

Comment: Thanks man!! worked like charm. My System: Ubuntu 16.04 64bit, Sublime3 build 3143.

Answer (score 10):

Apparently there is an undocumented `toggle_menu` command, so you can bind a key to it. But <kbd>Alt</kbd> alone does not seem to work - I guess because it's a modifier key for SLT.

*.../User/Default (Linux).sublime-keymap*:

```py
[
    { "keys": ["f10"], "command": "toggle_menu"}
]
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, +1!

Comment: this was also just what I've been searching for for some time! great.

Answer (score 9):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>

Search for `menu`

Click on `view: Toggle Menu`

It will work

Comment: That was all I was looking for, after hiding the menu and not knowing how to show it again. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: This answer is the same as top answer, with no additional information or what so ever.

Answer (score 8):

Simple pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> works for me. I'm using sublime text 3

Answer (score 7):

In Windows, you can press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and menu will reappear .

In Linux, You need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> then menu will appear in center of the screen then you need to choose `View -> Hide/Show Menu` menu entry.

Then this will be permanently set as default.

Answer (score 7):

For me it worked this way:

I am using ubuntu 18.05 lts

**ctrl+shift+p** and then you get a search bar with all options. Type **view** and select **View: Toggle menu**

it will appear back automatically.

Answer (score 2):

In case there are other Linux/Ubuntu/Gnome Desktop Environment n00bs out there, like me, note that the menus may appear at the top of the screen rather than the top of the window, as per the screen shot below:

[Gnome Desktop Environment menu for Sublime Text 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YadtB.png)

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, folow below steps

> 1. Close sublime text
> 2. Go to /home/-user-directory-/.config/sublime-text-version-/Local/
> 3. vim/edit Session.sublime_session
> 4. Look for the last line with “menu_visible”:false,
> 5. change value to true
> 6. Save the file
> 7. Reopen sublime text

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. And the solutions didn`t wok: there wasn't view -> Hide/Show Menu; neither there wasn't View: Toggle menu.

From this post below I found a comment from @MattDMo explaining the following:

"The default Adaptive theme doesn't show the menu, just the hamburger. To get the menu back, go to Preferences -> Select Theme… and choose anything other than Adaptive.sublime-theme."

[how to show the menu bar in sublime text 4 (windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68033366/how-to-show-the-menu-bar-in-sublime-text-4-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Preferences** -> **Settings**.  To the file on the right in the curly braces add the following.  Was the only way that I found to use a theme other than default and get the menu bar back.

"themed_title_bar": false,

Comment: Forgot to add, Save the file and your menu bar should come back.

Answer (score 0):

None of the options worked for me (Win 11), only solution is to uninstall including manually removing any remaining Sublime folders as in, Users<UserName>\AppData\Local and Users<UserName>\AppData\Roaming, then reinstall...

Also note... Ctr + Shift + P doesn't show any Toggle Menu option (but does after you fix it)...

Note 2... problem happened after installing theme but affected all themes so changing theme didn't fix it, I tried several...