# how to show the menu bar in sublime text 4 (windows)

Tags: settings, sublimetext4

I updated my sublime text after which I can't seem to see my menu bar on top of the screen but now have to click the 3 lines button to view it.is there any way to make show the menu bar like normal again?

I tried going to "view" and enabling it  but I can't find any "menu bar setting"

[image]

Answer (score 13):

I think showing the hamburger menu is a feature of your current theme.
Try changing your theme **Preferences-->Select Theme**

Alternatively customize your theme **Preferences-->Customize Theme**
(refer to your themes documentation).

Customize the rules in the theme file as required.

[See the sublime forum post](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/city-lights-theme-title-bar-disappeared-after-upgrade/57888)

Example found from the link above, works for the adaptive theme:

```
"rules":
[
    {
        "class": "title_bar",
        "bg": "#0000"
    }
]
```

Happy Coding:)

Comment: This is the correct answer. The default `Adaptive` theme doesn't show the menu, just the hamburger. To get the menu back, go to `Preferences -> Select Theme…` and choose anything other than `Adaptive.sublime-theme`.

Comment: Is there a way to change the menubar while keeping my current theme?
I tried different themes like Agila, gruvbox and all of them show the menubar with hamburger.
I don't want to keep the default sublime theme.

Comment: @RaghavArora Answer has been updated to include additional information on customizing themes.

Comment: this was driving me nuts after a recent update. thanks!

Comment: This worked! Once you've clicked `Preferences -> Customize Theme` - copy and paste the code above into `\User\<theTheme>.sublime-theme` window that pops up

Comment: I am using "Material Theme". After customising the theme, you have to run `window.run_command("toggle_menu")` in the console to show the menu. The command is from @MattDMo's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of strange, as my View menu has a Hide/Show Menu option on it right near the top. At any rate, to show the menu (or hide it again), select **`View → Show Console`** (or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>) and enter the following command:

```py
window.run_command("toggle_menu")
```

and the menu should show up again.

Comment: hi , so i copied the code u suggested and pasted  it in the console, and pressed "enter" (also i apologize if this is the wrong way to do it,I am quite new to this) 

there was no change after I did this . is there anything that I am doing wrong or have to further do?

Comment: @doctorbyte see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68062204/1426065). Changing your theme away from `Adaptive` (and themes based on it) is the correct way to solve your problem.